# SQL Server group by alternative by subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Can any of you guide me, which query will execute faster?

1st query:

```
Select 
    t1.*, t2.CountDuplicate 
From 
    Table1 t1
Inner Join 
    (Select 
         ID, Name, Count(*) as CountDuplicate 
     From 
         Table1 
     Group By 
         ID, Name) t2 on t2.Id = t1.Id
```

2nd query:

```
Select 
    t1.*, 
    (Select Count(t2.*) 
     From Table1 t2 
     Where t2.Id = t1.Id 
     Group By t2.ID, t2.Name) as CountDuplicate 
From 
    Table1 t1
```

Comment: Thanks for edit :)

Comment: Have you run `EXPLAIN` on each query, or at least tested it?  The answer to your question could depend on the size of the tables.

Comment: well the size of table will not exceed by 1000, and I forgot to wrote that, I will fetch the records in #temp table

Comment: The first query should probably run faster, as the derived table select only happens once, while in the second query the sub query will execute for each row in the outer query. However, the best way to figure out is to compare the execution plan for both queries.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I agree, but the first query must do a full table scan on the subquery, while the second does a full subquery on each record of the first table.  I could see it going either way, maybe the OP will benchmark with his data and let us know.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hence the "probably" :-)

Comment: Just use `set statistics io on` and see yourself which uses less I/O.

Comment: *If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then **race your horses*** - see [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) by Eric Lippert for more background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to specify the second query is:

```
Select t1.*, 
       (Select Count(*) 
        From Table1 t2
        where t2.Id = t1.Id 
       ) as CountDuplicate 
From Table1 t1;
```

I don't know why you have a `name` in the `group by`.  You might want `and t2.name = t1.name` in the conditions.

No `group by` is necessary in the subquery.

Which works faster depends on a number of factors.  For this version to be performance, you need an index on `table1(id)`.  However, the best way to write this query is:

```
select t1.*, count(*) over (partition by id) as CountDuplicate
from table1 t1;
```

This should have the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

`The First Query will run Faster`

**Reason:**

1. The first query will execute two queries separately `only once` and join their result sets together to get the final result set, a nice clean set based approach.
2. On the other hand in the second query the Outer query will be executed once but the inner query will be executed for each row returned by the outer query, say if your outer query returns 1000 rows the inner query will be executed 1000 times.

Stick with the option One.